# Realm - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on

Tags: android, realm

I keep getting this crash on Fabric which is affecting a few of our users but it's been very hard to replicate. It seems to happen randomly and most of the times it work fine. U

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?
   at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.nativeGetString(UncheckedRow.java)
   at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.getString(UncheckedRow.java:157)
   at io.realm.com_pitchero_ph_features_schedule_model_training_SessionRealmProxy.realmGet$venue(com_pitchero_ph_features_schedule_model_training_SessionRealmProxy.java:275)
   at com.pitchero.ph.databinding.RowScheduleTrainingBinding.executeBindings(RowScheduleTrainingBinding.java:125)
   at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:437)
   at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:409)
   at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$7.run(ViewDataBinding.java:194)
   at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$8.doFrame(ViewDataBinding.java:286)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:957)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

The objects are saved to Realm like this:

```
 public static void saveRealmObjects(final RealmList<RealmObject> objects,
                                    Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess onSuccess,
                                    Realm.Transaction.OnError error) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(objects);
            }
        }, onSuccess, error);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "saveRealmObjects error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and there's a query which has a listener attached to receive updates and update the UI accordingly:

```
 dbQueryFixtures = query
            .equalTo(Fixture.FIELD_CLUB_ID, String.valueOf(club.clubId))
            .equalTo(Fixture.FIELD_MEMBER_ID, getMemberId())
            .findAllAsync();
    dbQueryFixtures.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Fixture>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Fixture> fixtures) {
            fixtures.sort(Fixture.FIELD_DATE, Sort.ASCENDING);
            final RealmList<Fixture> results = new RealmList<>();
            results.addAll(dbQueryFixtures);
            getEventsHistoryFromDB(results, logic);
        }
    });
```

Once an update is received, the results are passed to a RecyclerView which updates the views. Each view uses DataBinding to get the values from the object. Eg.:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="session"
        type="Session"/>

    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

and

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/schedule_training_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@{session.venue}"
                android:textColor="@color/grayLight"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                tools:text="Training session"/>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated as I have not been able to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: What version of Realm are we talking about? `sort` used like this would be a no-op since 0.89.0.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce We're using Realm 5.0.1. This is quite old code I think so that's why sort is used that way